# How to get the name of the parent folder of a file specified by its full path?

Tags: matlab, string-parsing

In Matlab, I have a string containing a path to a file:

```
path = 'C:/Data/Matlab/Dir/file.m'
```

I want now want to extract the '`Dir`' part of the string. One way to do this is:

```
[first, second, third, fourth, fifth] = strtok(path, '/')
```

And then take the `fourth` element, and finally remove the first character from it (the `/`).

I'm just wondering if there is a more elegant solution? It seems a little cumbersome to have to explicitly store all the `first` ... `fifth` elements and then manually remove the `/`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
parts = strsplit(path, '/');
DirPart = parts{end-1};
```

Comment: This is not agnostic to OS. See the answer using `filesep`, which evaluates to `/` or `\\` depending on the OS.

Answer (score 16):

you can try the fileparts function as follow:

```
[ParentFolderPath] = fileparts('C:/Data/Matlab/Dir/file.m');
[~, ParentFolderName] = fileparts(ParentFolderPath) ;
ParentFolderName = 'Dir'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
parts = strsplit(file_path, filesep);
parent_path = strjoin(parts(1:end-1), filesep);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
s = regexp(path, '/', 'split')
s(4)
```

as described [here](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) at "Split String at Delimiter using split Keyword".

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to care about the number of elements of your path, and you don't want to use `strsplit`, which is not available in older versions of Matlab, you can also use this one liner:

```
directory = getfield( fliplr(regexp(fileparts(path),'/','split')), {1} )

%% or:
% alldir = regexp(fileparts(path),'/','split')
% directory = alldir(end)
```

which will always return the parent folder of the specified file.

You should also consider using `filesep` instead of `'/'` to get better compatibility with various systems.

Answer (score 1):

Max solution is good for windows, but might fail on linux/mac due to the slash at the beginning of absolute paths. My suggestion would be:

```
parts = strsplit(path, filesep);
DirPart = parts{end-1};
if path(1) == filesep
    DirPart = [filesep,DirPart];
end
if path(end) == filesep
    DirPart = [DirPart,filesep];
end
```

Answer (score 1):

find the parent directory with a single line of code if you don't know how many folders are layering

```
fliplr(strtok(fliplr(pname),'\'))
```

Answer (score -1):

there is also the good old way...

```
n=size(path,2);

while path(n)~='/'; n=n-1; end

i=n-2;

while path(i)~='/'; i=i-1; end

% result
path(i+1:n-1)
```